# Springboot 405 Method Not Allowed in Pivotal Web Services/Cloud Foundry but working in local docker

Tags: spring-boot, docker, cloud-foundry, http-status-code-405, pivotal-web-services

I have created REST API application in SpringBoot which has `GET` and `POST` method pointing to the same URL. I have created springboot application and deployed in docker container in my local machine. When I try to access this application, I am able to get response for both `GET` and `POST` methods. I have deployed the same application into Pivotal Web Services (Pivotal Cloud Foundry). When I try to access `GET` method in PWS, it works fine but when I try to access `POST` method, I am getting error.

```
`"error": "Method Not Allowed",
"message": "Request method 'POST' not supported",`
```

If I look at the error in PWS log, I could see the following.
`.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]`

I have tried to change the springboot code to include different options in the method but none of them seem to work in PWS.

I would like to see **200 OK** for POST method.

`````
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/skus")
public class SKUController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();



    //==============================================================

    @Autowired
    SKUService skuService; //Service which will do all data retrieval/manipulation work

    // -------------------Retrieve All SKUS---------------------------------------------

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<SKU>> listAllSKUS() {
        List<SKU> skus  = skuService.listAllSKUS();
        if (skus.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
            // You many decide to return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<List<SKU>>(skus, HttpStatus.OK);
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> addSKU(@RequestBody SKU sku) {
        try {
            skuService.addSKU(sku);
            return new ResponseEntity<SKU>(sku, HttpStatus.OK);

        }catch(Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity("SKU cannot be created", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
}


````
`````

Comment: how are you invoking the url? Kindly share the url along with the payload for post method.

Comment: A code snippet of your controller would be helpful as well. Please include that too.

Comment: POST /skus/100 HTTP/1.1
Host: service-url
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: b7eaaf12-1106-2d94-e987-1f6bf232c9de
{"id": 1999, "productId": "PR009","name": "Product-9","description": "Product9 Desc","price": 800,"count":800}

Comment: I have added code snippet. please check and let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Your `@RequestMapping` is for the root path `/skus/`, but you are `POST`ing to `/skus/100`. If you want to use the `100` as the entity ID for the added SKU, you should change the mapping to something like `/skus/{skuId}` and add a `@PathVariable` as a method argument.

Comment: I did try with the URL /skus/ only for my POST request. I added 100 for another get method.